# Oracle: read XML using XMLTable

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g, xml-parsing

I'd like to read a XML using XMLTABLE but I would like my PATH be a varchar2 instead of a string. I'm trying to do it but I'm getting the error "ORA-01780: string literal required"

Example:

```
path1 VARCHAR2(100);
path2 VARCHAR2(100);
path3 VARCHAR2(100);
path4 VARCHAR2(100);

begin

path1 :='persons/employees/emp';
path2 :='persons/employees/name';
path3 :='persons/employees/job';
path4 :='persons/employees/hire';

SELECT xt.*
FROM   xml_tab x,
       XMLTABLE('/company/person'
         PASSING x.xml_data
         COLUMNS 
           "EMPNO"    VARCHAR2(4)  PATH path1,
           "ENAME"    VARCHAR2(10) PATH path2,
           "JOB"      VARCHAR2(9)  PATH path3,
           "HIREDATE" VARCHAR2(11) PATH path4
         ) xt;
```

Does anyone knows if there is any way to use a varchar2 variable type after PATH instaead of writing the path directly?

Comment: Please check paths in question text: `persons` vs `person` and `employees` vs `employee` ...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use dynamic paths for retrieving node values from initial XML just use XQuery parameter and `name()` in XPath to construct fixed XML structure regardless of source XML structure:

```
declare

  vXML xmltype := xmltype('
    <company>
      <persons>
        <employee>
          <emp>emp-01</emp>
          <name>name-01</name>
          <job>job-01</job>
          <hire>hire-01</hire>
        </employee>
        <employee>
          <emp>emp-02</emp>
          <name>name-02</name>
          <job>job-02</job>
          <hire>hire-02</hire>
        </employee>
      </persons>
    </company>
  ');

  vXQueryText varchar2(4000) := '
    for $cur_emp in $doc/company/persons/employee
      return
        <result>
          <emp_name>{$cur_emp/*[name()=$node_path]}</emp_name>
        </result>
  ';

  vNodePath varchar2(4000);

  procedure print_node_values(pNodePath in varchar2)
  is
  begin

    dbms_output.put_line('--- Values of "'||pNodePath||'" node ---');

    for cTest in (
      select * 
      from 
        XMLTable(vXQueryText
          passing 
            vXML         as "doc",
            pNodePath as "node_path"
          columns
            emp_name varchar2(4000) path '/result/emp_name'
        )
    )
    loop
      dbms_output.put_line('emp_name: ' || cTest.emp_name);
    end loop;
  end;

begin

  print_node_values('name');
  print_node_values('job');

end;
```

This example prints following:

```
--- Values of "name" node ---
emp_name: name-01
emp_name: name-02
--- Values of "job" node ---
emp_name: job-01
emp_name: job-02
```

Of course, you can specify more than one variable in `XMLTable()` parameters to access more nodes and process it in single query.